# Simple way to temporary exclude a job from running on a node in a label group

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl

I wan't to be able to temporary exclude a specific job from running on a node in a label group.

jobA, jobB, jobC are tied to run on label general
nodeA,nodeB,nodeC have the label general on them.

Let's say that jobA starts to fail consistently on nodeA.

The only solutions that I see today are taking nodeA offline for all jobs or reconfigure many jobs or nodes which is pretty time consuming. We are using JOB-DSL to configure the jobs so changing in the job configuration requires a checkin.

An ideal situation for us would be to have a configuration on the node:
Exclude job with name: jobA

Is there some easy way to configure that jobA should temporarily only run on nodeB and node C and that jobB/C should still run on all nodes in label general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a parameterized job to run some job-dsl configuration.  Make one of the parameters a "Choice" listing the job names that you might want to change.

Another parameter would select a label defining the node(s) you want to run the job on.  (You can have more than one label on a node).

The job-dsl script then updates the job label.
This groovy script will enable/disable all jobs in a folder:

```
// "State" job parameter (choice, DISABLED|ENABLED)
def targetState = ('DISABLED'.equalsIgnoreCase(State))

// "Folder" job parameter (choice or free-text)
def targetFolderPath = Folder.trim() 

def folder = findFolder(jenkins, targetFolderPath)
println "Setting all jobs in '${folder.name}' to '${targetState}'"
for (job in folder.getAllJobs()) {
    job.disabled = targetState
    println "updated job: ${job.name}"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I just came across the same issue, I want the job to run on the device with lable, say "lableA", but do not want it to run on device with lable "lableB".
We may try this:

```
node(nodeA && !nodeB) {
}
```

Refer to: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#node-allocate-node

Answer (score 0):

you can also use **NodeLabel Parameter Plugin** in jobA. Using this plugin you can define nodes on which the job should be allowed to be executed on. Just add parameter node and select all nodes but nodeA.
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeLabel+Parameter+Plugin

Answer (score 0):

For a simple quick exclude, what I think the original question refers to as "The only solutions that I see today are ... reconfigure ... jobs or nodes" see this other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29611255/598656

Answer (score 0):

To stop using a node with a given label, one strategy is to simply change the label. E.g. suppose the label is

**BUILDER**

changing the label to

**-BUILDER**

will preserve information for the administrator but any job using `BUILDER` as the label will not select that node.

To allow a job to run on the node, you can change the node selection to

`BUILDER||-BUILDER`

A useful paradigm when shuffling labels around.

**NOTE** that jobs may still select using the prior label for a period of time.