# Restrict Jenkins Job To Linux Slaves

Tags: jenkins

How do I restrict my Jenkins job to just run on Linux slaves?

I have ticked the **Restrict where this project can be run** box but it seems I can only put the slave names in there.

I want to say *Use any slave that is running on the linux platform*

Similar to the teamcity.agent.jvm.os.name equals Linux option in TeamCity.

EDIT: So far it looks like you have to manually edit each slave's label (or script it). Unfortunately, I don't have rights to change these, so I will keep this question open in case someone comes up with an alternative or a plugin or something.

Comment: You should at least have right to create a job. If so then you can create a job as answered by me below. I don't think there is any other option to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there. Simply label your linux slaves with the tag "linux" or the like and enter that string into the **Restrict where this project can be run** field. Use Manage Jenkins > Manage Nodes to add the label to the appropriate slaves.

Answer (score 4):

1. If the number of Linux slaves is less you can go to configure option of the slave and add label as 'Linux' to it.
2. Then go to the job configuration and select '**Restrict where this project can be run**' and add label as Linux. :)

If the number of Linux slaves is large then configuring all slaves manually is a hectic task. You can automate it easily using groovy. Create a job test job that will updated all the labels of linux slaves with 'Linux' Label. Select the **build step as groovy** and paste the script below:

```
// First Get Node Instance<br>
// Then for each node instance check if its 'Remote FS root' starts 
// with forward slash. Which means its a linux slave. If it is then 
// add label Linux to it.
def Nodes=jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getNodes();
Nodes.each { currentNode ->
  if (currentNode.getRemoteFS().toLowerCase().startsWith("/")) {
     if (! currentNode.getLabelString().contains("Linux")) {
      currentNode.setLabelString(currentNode.getLabelString()+" Linux")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Using Groovy to automate updates is a great idea, but it's worth mentioning that it requires the [Groovy plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin). There are a number of ways to get the slave OS without relying on a remote path: `currentNode.computer.unix` is a boolean or `currentNode.computer.systemProperties['os.name'] == "Linux"`. Also, it's a good idea to experiment in the [Jenkins Script Console](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+Script+Console) before applying global changes.

Comment: I don not prefer relying on OS name specially if the slaves are created as vsphere slaves. It fails in case of slave agents that are set to shutdown in idle time. The groovy script is not able to detect the OS name if the slave agent is offline.